# what's causing terraform error: Call to function "formatlist" failed: error on format iteration 0: unsupported value for "%s" at 5: string required

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

In my terraform code I have the following locals

```
locals {
    merged_acl_contributors = concat(var.workspace.acl.contributors, azurerm_synapse_workspace.workspace.identity)
    contributors = formatlist("user:%s:rwx", local.merged_acl_contributors)
}
```

var.workspace.acl.contributors does not have a value (just has []).  When I try to deploy this I get:

```
│ Error: Error in function call
│ 
│   on modules/synapse_v2/main.tf line 10, in locals:
│   10:   contributors        = formatlist("user:%s:rwx", local.merged_acl_contributors)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.merged_acl_contributors is tuple with 1 element
│ 
│ Call to function "formatlist" failed: error on format iteration 0:
│ unsupported value for "%s" at 5: string required.
```

Comment: Can you share the value for `local.merged_acl_contributors`?

Comment: The two elements in local.merged_acl_contributors are var.workspace.acl.contributors and azurerm_synapse_workspace.workspace.identity.  Since var.workspace.acl.contributors is empty, i.e. just "[]", the value for local.merged_acl_contributors is azurerm_synapse_workspace.workspace.identity.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what's happening?

Comment: Looking at local.merged_acl_contributors was the answer.  The value was wrong.  Instead of azurerm_synapse_workspace.identity, it needed azurerm_synapse_workspace.managedidentity

Answer (score 0):

[identity](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/synapse_workspace#identity) in `azurerm_synapse_workspace.workspace` is a **block** with multiple attributes. You have to choose what you want. For example:

```
merged_acl_contributors = concat(var.workspace.acl.contributors, [azurerm_synapse_workspace.workspace.identity.principal_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `local.merged_acl_contributors` was the answer. The value was wrong. Instead of `azurerm_synapse_workspace.identity`, it needed to be `azurerm_synapse_workspace.managedidentity`.